# counting slugs not working?

Tags: php

I'm trying to restart a site from 2020, and I have a counter that counts how many "cats" i have as tags, and how many of them that are listed to be allowed.
So I have a tag "cat" and a category "allowpost".

This is the code to check if it's allowed:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // only posts that have both taxonomies will return.
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'cat', //cat
        ),
        array(
          'taxonomy' => 'category',
          'field'    => 'slug',
          'terms'    => 'allowpost', //allowpost
        ),
      ),
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    $countallowed = count($posts);
    echo $countallowed ;
```

and this is the counter of total:

```
 <?php
$term = get_term_by('slug', cat, post_tag);
echo $term->count;
```

And it worked, (in 2020), Now I'm however getting: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "cat"**

And I have no idea what's wrong... anybody got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I'm however getting: **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined
> constant "cat"**

That's because the `cat` and `post_tag` were not wrapped in quotes (e.g. `'cat'`), and they also did not start with the dollar sign (`$`) as in `$cat`, which indicates a variable, hence PHP tried to find the [constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.syntax.php) named `cat` or `post_tag`, and when the constants do not exist or are not defined, then PHP throws the above error. [More details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2941174/9217760).

So I believe the code should instead be written like so: `$term = get_term_by('slug', 'cat', 'post_tag');`.

Also, an additional note: You can actually simply use the [`found_posts` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) of a `WP_Query` class instance, to get the total number of posts in your query. Just use `'posts_per_page' => 1` and *not* `'posts_per_page' => -1`, then use `new WP_Query` instead of `get_posts()` to get the count. I.e.

```php
/* Replace this:
$posts = get_posts($args);
$countallowed = count($posts);
*/

// with this one:
$query = new WP_Query($args);
$countallowed = $query->found_posts;
```